# Change URL link based on user input PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I've seen this posted a couple times however I can't seem to relate it to my own work. I'm making a weather site as a project by using the html on another site and I'm trying to change the url in a fashion similar to this:
/www.weather.com/location/' + $location + '/forecast. Which I have managed in the past with Node.js.
Anyway, here is my code, anything you peeps could do to help would be greatly appreciated.

The id and name of the input type is 'city'

EDIT: I have updated my code to edit the url in js and make an ajax post. I'm still having trouble outputting any results...

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(e) {  
      var inputvalue = $("#city").val();
      var location = 'http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/' + inputvalue + '/forecasts/latest'
 $.post({
  location;
 )};
});
};
```

PHP:

```
$location = $_GET['location'];
if($location) {
   $forecast = file_get_contents('$location');
$file_array = explode('3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">', $forecast); 
$file_array2 = explode('</span></span></span>', $file_array[1]);  
echo $file_array2[0];
};
```

Comment: Where is the Ajax request?

Comment: Javascript should probably be doing an ajax request to PHP on click. Or make the request directly to the weather site and spit it out however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need php you can just change url right in the submit handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(e) {  
  var inputvalue = $("#city").val();
  location.href='/www.weather.com/location/' + inputvalue + '/forecast'

});
});
```

or if trying to do something more than go to new url use an ajax post

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(e) {  
  var inputvalue = $("#city").val();
 $.post(
 {
    location: inputvalue
 }

});
});
```

and on that same page (or wherever you redirect) you check for a get variable

```
$location = $_GET['location']
if($location){
echo 'your html or whatever';
}
```